# Debian 8.10.0 installation on PowerPC can't use CD-ROM

Tags: debian, mount, system-installation, powerpc

So, I'm having an old PowerPC based IBM server, RS/6000 F50- that I'd like to get running simply for my own fun and hobby. There are several different OSes that can be installed on it and I was going to try out the Debian 8.10.0. The server boots from the CD-ROM, but after the installer loads and asks first few basic questions, it stops with an error:

```
No common CD-ROM drive was detected.
```

After that if offers me to load a driver from the floppy, select cdrom device manually or I can run installer shell. I tried to find out more in the shell. I see that there is a device /dev/cdrom that links to /dev/sr0. I tried to read some data from /dev/sr0 using a dd and I see data coming from it. blkid detects CD FS as iso9660. I tried to mount device /dev/sr0 to /cdrom with no luck. Command:

```
mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /cdrom/
```

fails with "Invalid argument". Is it possible that installer does not support the file system that's on its own CD? What could be the possible solutions to mount the CD-ROM drive?
I also tried netinst image, but it stops the same way. I tried to install AIX 4.3.3, it installs but with some other unrelated issues.
I have some older Debian images that I'll try out too.
The server is in minimal configuration - no additional cards, one HDD, one CD-ROM, no video, console only.

Comment: Have you run full hardware diagnostic? Have you try AIX 5.3 (IMHO it is supported).Do you have special need of Debian on Power because on Power is very good to run AIX, on Sparc - Solaris, etc.

Comment: @RomeoNinov No, I chose to start with Debian just because I'm familiar with it. I will install AIX in future so it would have its dedicated OS.
To be honest, I don't know how to perform a hardware diagnostic. AIX i stallation starts without any CD-ROM problems.

Comment: About "no video, console only" with AIX, Solaris you should be ready for: 1. text only console. 2. `ksh`/`sh` 3. `vi` :)

Comment: Hardware diagnostic can be done by booting and press F5 (5 on serial terminal)

Comment: At the moment I'm getting further with Debian 6. Installation works smoothly, but after first reboot it hangs with message "disk-label: can't load from this device". Will investigate further into this.
AIX 4.3.3 also installs smoothly, boots, but no login on serial. I assume that it needs video output.

Comment: In debian did you set in `fstab` to mount via labels. You can edit to mount from disks, something like: `/dev/hdisk0`. Also you can try to use LVM (as in AIX)